# What is this creepy place?

Tags: terraria

So I'm playing Terraria 1.2, delving in the underground beneath a regular ol' Forest biome, when suddenly I stumble into this place.

[image]

The cute little critter at the bottom is a Cochnial Beetle.

The background is completely different from any underground biome I've ever seen, and I can't find this biome listed in the page of [biomes](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Environment).

What is this?

Comment: I assumed that's the darker side of the Mushroom Biome. Because they're connected to each other in my world. Either that or it is the Underground Crimson?

Comment: I think it's just an aesthetic cave. I've never seen anything unique in them other than the background and red moss. It's also definitely not underground Crimson. Those beetles can be found anywhere underground AFAIK.

Comment: It's not part of the mushroom biome.  This isn't connected to one at all.

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk You're right. There are no special blocks, so it cannot be anything terribly important. It's just there to look nice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [changelog](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nubZZSGBoUiuKFKzWT7raMrPI35MQtDWSsL-MbHFgqs/preview?sle=true) (under "graphical changes," on page 3):

> There are several new mini caves that can be found with unique backgrounds

You appear to have found one.

By the way, [that Cochineal Beetle](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Cochineal_Beetle) can spawn anywhere in the Cavern layer; it's not specific to these "mini-caves." It just spawns very rarely.

Comment: It's an especially creepy mini-cave.  It certainly caught my attention!  Thank you, Doorknob.